# background-image:no-repeat not working at all

Tags: css

I am using blow code in CSS.
repeat property is not working.
I tried repeat-x, repeat-y, repeat, no-repeat...All are giving same result.

```css
#parentDIV {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-image: url("img/newimage.jpg");
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

Comment: post a snippet example with `<>` tools

Comment: use background-size instead of width or height and please give us your html code.

Comment: It's really hard to guess what other thing you might have done to cause that because the CSS looks fine

Comment: “*All are giving same result*”... which is what exactly? It is impossible to figure out what is causing a problem when we don’t have the code that’s causing it, or even know what the problem is!

Comment: Welcome to the StackOverflow @Abdul Kindly visit the following link  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example which will help on how and what to ask

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this snippet because it is working fine.

```css
.parent {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/200");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">

</div>
```

Comment: I think he has done some other thing to cause that problem which he hasn't mentioned in the question

Comment: Yeah! I guess it could be missing `<div>` or something like that which might have caused the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
I tried the one you (Abhishek) told me and it really worked.
but can you please tell me, why my code wasn't working?

Comment: Update your question by adding the HTML of the following CSS then we can come to some conclusion. Because there are various factors for not working.

Comment: Thanks to everybody for guiding me.
I am able to fix my code. There was problem with HTML code.